# NavigationView - When selected settings item there is no way to unselect it from code

Tags: c#, uwp

I've found some strange behavior. If SelectedItem is SettingsItem then cannot deselect it from code

XAML:

```cs
<NavigationView Name="nv">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="dsadas" />
        <NavigationViewItem Content="dsadas" />
        <NavigationViewItem Content="dsadas" />
        <NavigationViewItem Content="dsadas" />
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="de select" />
</NavigationView>
```

CS:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    nv.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

And that is all. I don't understand why code doesn't work for Settings Item and how to deal with this problem.

Comment: Try `nv.SelectedIndex = -1`

Comment: @FurkanKambay `NavigationView` does not have a `SelectedIndex` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending @Martin-Zikmund answer. Code handling now situation if ItemsSource is set.

```
public static class NavigationViewExtension
{
    public static void ClearSelection(this NavigationView navigationView)
    {
        var temporaryItem = new NavigationViewItem();

        if (navigationView.MenuItemsSource != null)
        {
            var existingList = ((IList)(navigationView.MenuItemsSource));
            existingList.Add(temporaryItem);
            navigationView.SelectedItem = temporaryItem;
            navigationView.SelectedItem = null;
            existingList.Remove(temporaryItem);
        }
        else
        {
            navigationView.MenuItems.Add(temporaryItem);
            navigationView.SelectedItem = temporaryItem;
            navigationView.SelectedItem = null;
            navigationView.MenuItems.Remove(temporaryItem);
        }
    }
}
```

This works for me completely

Comment: If you have resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later, Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

This is very interesting bug in the `NavigationView`, I have created a [GitHub repro](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/NavigationViewSettingsDeselect) and reported it via [Feedback Hub](https://aka.ms/Brmuue).

As a workaround I have created the following "hack" extension method:

```
public static class NavigationViewExtensions
{
    public static void ClearSelection(this NavigationView navigationView)
    {
        var temporaryItem = new NavigationViewItem();
        navigationView.MenuItems.Add(temporaryItem);
        navigationView.SelectedItem = temporaryItem;
        navigationView.SelectedItem = null;
        navigationView.MenuItems.Remove(temporaryItem);
    }
}
```

How does it work? The code temporarily adds a new `NavigationViewItem` to the control and selects it (thus deselecting the Settings item). Then it clears the selection and a removes the temporary item right away. Because the view is updated on the UI thread, you will never be able to notice the new item being added and removed again.

Comment: Works like a charm when items are set explicitly but throws Critical Exception if ItemsSource is set to some list unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, that is true. In that case the solution would be to add the temporary item to that list instead of the `MenuItems` collection.

Comment: From my test it seems that it is necessary for the temporary item to be in the list for the settings item to be deselected properly. Alternatively you could temporarily select the first menu item for example, but you would have to make sure you don't navigate to a page or perform any unwanted action.

Comment: I let myself to extend your @MartinZikmund 's solution

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to solve it.

You need to add hidden item to NavigationView:

```
<NavigationView Name="nv">
  <NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <NavigationViewItem Content="dsadas" />
    <NavigationViewItem Content="dsadas" />
    <NavigationViewItem Content="dsadas" />
    <NavigationViewItem Content="dsadas" />
    <NavigationViewItem x:Name="HiddenItem" Visibility="Collapsed" />
  </NavigationView.MenuItems>
<Button Click="Button_Click" Content="de select" />
```

And then you can clear selection:

```
nv.SelectedItem = HiddenItem;
```